# Collapsed navbar not closing on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are similar questions posted but the solutions aren't working for me. Can anyone help me take a look?

I tried shifting the data-toggle and data-target into ahref too but it doesn't work. Not sure if it has anything to do with the css. Thanks for the help in advance!

```css
.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.navbar-brand {
  height: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navbar a.navbar-brand span {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  height: 52px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4679b2;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav>.nav-header {
  display: inline;
}

.nav>.nav-header>.nav-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav>.nav-btn {
  display: none;
}

.nav>.nav-links {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav>.nav-links>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efefef;
}

.nav>.nav-links>a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.nav>#nav-check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:850px) {
  .nav>.nav-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .nav>.nav-btn>label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 13px;
  }
  .nav>.nav-btn>label:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .nav>.nav-btn>label>span {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  }
  .nav>.nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    top: 50px;
  }
  .nav>.nav-links>a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav>#nav-check:not(:checked)+.nav-links {
    height: 0px;
  }
  .nav>#nav-check:checked+.nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-links" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse.in">
  <a href="#!/displayAuditorium">Auditorium</a>
  <a href="#!/displayExhibition">Exhibition</a>
  <a href="#!/displayHotel">Hotel</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the data-target attribute should reference an id. You referenced .nav-collapse.in, which is a class.

Try to give your nav-bar an id.